# window.open() is not working in IE6 and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a dotnet application in which I have to close the current window and then open the new window again in runtime. I have used Javascript for it. The code is as follows:

```
function OpenNewWindow() {
    if (ConfirmStartTest()) {
        closeWindow();

window.open("OnlineTestFrame.aspx", "_Parent", "model=yes,dailog=no,top=0,height=screen.height,width=screen.width,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,zoominherit =0,resizable =no,scrollbars=yes,dependent=no,directories=no,taskbar=no,fullscreen=yes");

        self.focus();

    }

}

//taking the confirmation for starting test
function ConfirmStartTest() {
    var result = confirm("Do you want to start the test now?");
    return result;
}

//function to close the current window
function closeWindow() {

     //var browserName = navigator.appName;

     //var browserVer = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);

     var ie7 = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest) ? true : false;  

     if (ie7) 

           {     

           //This method is required to close a window without any prompt for IE7
           window.open('','_parent','');
           window.close();

           }

     else 

           {

           //This method is required to close a window without any prompt for IE6

           this.focus();

           self.opener = this;

           self.close();

           }
}
```

Now, when I am running this application in IE7 and IE6, it is not running. But, in IE8 it is running fine.

This code was working fine for all IE6 n IE7 previously. All of a sudden it is giving error.Its not able to open the new window and stopping abruptly in b/w.

If anyonw has any idea regarding this, please let me know.

Comment: You say that it suddenly stopped working - what changes did you make prior to that?

Comment: Also, I don't see the initialization of the "self" variable, are you missing that, or is it outside of the snippet?

Comment: @Niklas - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.self

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like closing a window and expecting anything after it to want to run.

Flow of the code

1. Function called
2. Close Window
3. Open window   <-- How can I run if parent is closed?
4. Focus window

[rant]
What you are trying to do here by forcing a user to use your own pop up window so it has no chrome is very bad user experience. You are deleting a users history. Leave my browser alone! There is a reason why you have to do hacky stuff to close a window, the browsers do not allow you to do it.
[/rant]

Comment: @Sean Before my rant section it does. Look at the flow. Close the window, than open a window. If the window closes, how can it run anymore JavaScript? It is like trying to walk out a door after closing it. It does not work.

Comment: Edited it so it is more clear to the people who did not understand my one sentence.

Comment: Better, now it relates to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the assignment of `self.opener`.

12/04 Microsoft started pushing out [Security Bulletin MS11-018](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms11-018.mspx) via Windows Update which closed of several vulnerabilities related to memory - one of these affected the `opener` property which no longer can be assigned to.

Comment: But, opener property coming into picture only if it is not IE7. My question is that it is not working for IE7. And, secondly it was working fine for all IE7, IE6, IE8 but now only working for IE8. And, i din make any chages in d code. Its the same. Can there be any possibility that I need to do some changes in internet explorer.

Comment: Then @epascarello's answer looks promising - but my answer is quite possibly correct for IE6